# C# Culture Specific symbols

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison, culture

In Latvian culture `lv-LV` there are special characters like 'ā', 'ī', 'ģ' etc.
Is there any built-in way, where following code returns true ?

```
var nameLv = "Jevģeņijs";

var nameEng = "Jevgenijs";

nameLv.Equals(nameEng, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Yeap, that will work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that applies [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086575/301857) to your code.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var nameLv = "Jevģeņijs";
    var nameEng = "Jevgenijs";

    var result = IsEquivalent(nameLv, nameEng);  // returns True
}

public static bool IsEquivalent(string latvian, string english)
{
    return english ==
        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(latvian));
}
```

I can't say whether this is the most robust method or will work given any particular strings, but [tested with your input](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3c2SkW) it seems to work fine.

There are [quite a few other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249087/301857) in that same thread that you might want to check out too.